# Problem with breakable tcolorbox and dashed line

Tags: tcolorbox

I have a problem with the dashed line in exercise 2, it does not take place correctly (start and end of pages 2,3 ...).

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=1.cm,bottom=2.cm,left=1cm,right=1.cm,heightrounded,marginparwidth=2cm,marginparsep=7mm]{geometry}

%---------------------------------------
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{Exercice}[2][]{%
%   borderline={2pt}{0mm}{black!45},
%   borderline west={1.5cm}{-1.55cm}{blue!15},
%   toptitle=1pt,%bottomtitle=2pt,
%   bottom=.5mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,
    top=4mm,
    colback=white,
    colframe=blue!10,
    colbacktitle=blue!10,
    borderline west={1.5pt}{15.6mm}{gray},
    borderline={1.5pt}{0mm}{gray},
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Exercice~\thetcbcounter~:\ #2,
    enhanced,
    leftrule=1.6cm,toprule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,if odd page*={overlay broken = {
    \draw[dashed,line width=1.5pt, gray, rounded corners]
    (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west);}}{overlay broken = {
    \draw[dashed,line width=1.5pt, gray, rounded corners]
    (frame.north east) -- (frame.north west);}},
    before upper={\parindent15pt},
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-3.2mm, xshift=2.cm},
    boxed title style={colframe=gray,boxrule=1.5pt},
    #1% For possible options
}
%---------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{Exercice}[]{}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}[]{}
\lipsum[5-12]
\end{Exercice}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor} % loaded by tikz
\usepackage[top=1.cm,bottom=2.cm,left=1cm,right=1.cm,heightrounded,marginparwidth=2cm,marginparsep=7mm]{geometry}

%---------------------------------------
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{Exercice}[2][]{
    top=4mm,
    colback=white,
    colframe=blue!10,
    colbacktitle=blue!10,
    borderline west={1.5pt}{15.6mm}{gray},
    borderline={1.5pt}{0mm}{gray},
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=Exercice~\thetcbcounter~:\ #2,
    enhanced,
    leftrule=1.6cm,
    toprule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    breakable,
    overlay first = {%
        \draw[dashed,line width=1.5pt, gray, rounded corners]
        (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west);
        },
    overlay middle = {%
        \draw[dashed,line width=1.5pt, gray, rounded corners]
        (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west);
        \draw[dashed,line width=1.5pt, gray, rounded corners]
                (frame.north east) -- (frame.north west);
        },
    overlay last = {%
        \draw[dashed,line width=1.5pt, gray, rounded corners]
        (frame.north east) -- (frame.north west);
        },
    before upper={\parindent15pt},
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-3.2mm, xshift=2.cm},
    boxed title style={colframe=gray,boxrule=1.5pt},
    #1% For possible options
}
%---------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{Exercice}[]{}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{Exercice}
\begin{Exercice}[]{}
\lipsum[5-20]
\end{Exercice}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much